# How could I make this inline?

Tags: python, tkinter

sorry I'm new with TKInter and Python in general, but I wanted to know if I could make `hello_world` fit inside `command=` when I'm defining `hello_button` (I don't know how I would look that up):

```
hello_btn = Button(gui, text="Hello World!", takefocus=0)
hello_btn.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="news")
def hello_world():
    hello_btn.configure(text="Hey, user!")
hello_btn.configure(command=hello_world)
```

Comment: You can use a `lambda` like this: `hello_btn.configure(command=lambda :hello_btn.configure(text="Hey, user!"))`

Comment: worked for me, thanks for the speed! Btw, would I need to change anything if the command wasn't a one-liner?

Comment: What makes you think this change will make it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `hello_btn` is defined in the global scope, all you'll need to do is move the function definition up above the button declaration so it doesn't cause a `NameError` complaining that `hello_world` is undefined

Here's a working example

```
import tkinter as tk

def hello_world():
    hello_btn.configure(text="Hey, user!")

gui = tk.Tk()

hello_btn = tk.Button(gui, text="Hello World!", takefocus=0, command=hello_world)
hello_btn.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="news")

gui.mainloop()
```